# Python: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: wrong path (on Output seems that Python modify my path )

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

hella.

seems to be a wrong path on my Python code. But I test again and again, the path and the file are good: `c:\Folder1\bebe.txt`

See the error `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'c:\\Folder1\x08ebe.txt'`

Python modify my path ??! Can you help me? Also, you have the entire code [HERE:](https://pastebin.com/yXfD1XK8)

[image]

Comment: Ture Pålsson's answer is correct about the escaping of strings - please consult it for more

Comment: yes, the answer may be correct, but that did not solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely this line:

```
file_path = 'C:\Something\booh'
```

In a Python [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), backslashes are used to introduce special characters. For example `\n` means a newline and `\b` means a backspace. To actually get a backslash, you have to type `\\`. A backslash followed by a character with no special meaning is left alone, so `\S` actually means `\S` (though relying on this is probably a bad idea).

You can either type your line like this

```
file_path = 'C:\\Something\\booh'
```

or use Pythons "raw string" syntax, which turns off the special meaning of backslashes, and type

```
file_path = r'C:\Something\booh'
```

Notice that when you do

```
s = '\\'
```

the string referred to by `s` actually contains a single backslash. For example, `len(s)` will be 1, and `print(s)` will print a single backslash.

Comment: the complete Python code is here:  https://pastebin.com/yXfD1XK8

Comment: try to change the line with path as follows: `file_path = "c:\\Folder1\bebe.txt'.replace('\', '\\')"`